# How do you send typed arrays over socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Hi I am trying to send a Int16Array from my node.js server to a browser client using socket.io. When I console.log the array client-side it gives me: "Object { 0: 1, 1: 25, 2: 45 }" instead of the expected output of "Int16Array(3) [ 1, 25, 45 ]". This confused me because the same command from client to server gave me the expected response.

Here's My Server:

```
    var myArray = [1, 25, 45];
    io.send( Int16Array.from(myArray) );
```

Here's My Client:

```
socket.on('message', function(x){ 
    console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Object types are not preserved when serialized via JSON.stringify, and I bet that's what's happening here. Try with [typeson](https://github.com/dfahlander/typeson)

Comment: Right, but apparently there's a way to send binary data, like in a typed array, directly without it being converted into json.

Comment: They handle those in a special manner, I guess. It's easy to check if what you want is possible - JSON that you get on the client should have an extension that would carry the type information, like $type is used by JSON .NET. Otherwise, the type information is lost

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` to just put the values of each object property into an array like so:

```
socket.on('message', function(x){ 
    console.log(Object.values(x));
});
```

More: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)